# Authenticating as Ubuntu on EC2 when ssh'd in via keypairs

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have an Ubuntu EC2 instance that I SSH in via ssh keypairs.

When I try to restart systemd it prompts for a password, which I don't have. I don't believe I set one up, and I have no idea what it would be, since I'm using the keypair to connect as the ubuntu user:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-37:~$ systemctl daemon-reload
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.reload-daemon ===
Authentication is required to reload the systemd state.
Authenticating as: Ubuntu (ubuntu)
Password:
polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Failed to execute operation: Access denied
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`?

Answer (score 9):

You need root permission to do that. Use

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be *the* answer, but it certainly is an answer because it worked for me in the same situation:

Execute the following command to elevate yourself to super user for the session:

```
sudo su
```

Info about `sudo su` (aka super user) [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/376386)

Answer (score -3):

Just run

```
sudo passwd ec2-user
```

To get your password!

Comment: `passwd` can be used to **set** a password, but never to get the current one - this should usually be impossible to the nonreversible hashing of the password.